# Error trying to start new activity on Android app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**My LOG CAT**

```
2021-05-26 19:04:51.813 25933-25933/com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp, PID: 25933
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp/com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp.Kayit_ol_acticvity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp.Kayit_ol_acticvity> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp.Kayit_ol_acticvity> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.AppComponentFactory>
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)**
```

**This is my logcat error I wanna switch between pages but I can't do this. Below you can find the code**

```java
package com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnNext;
    Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.kayıtol);



        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Intent ıntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                Intent ıntent = new Intent(context, Kayit_ol_acticvity.class);

                startActivity(ıntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```java
    
    package com.melikerdemkoc.myvetapp;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    class Kayit_ol_acticvity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.kayit_ol);
        }
    }
```

**I'm getting lines like this in my code, unfortunately, I haven't found a solution, I would appreciate it if you could help me! Thanks in advance!**

**In this code, my purpose was to direct you to the signup page when you click REGISTER.**
**Intent is so important pls send codes for my project if you do this ım so happy thank you ı need this

Answer (score 1):

Your error says the class is not accessible.

You've defined the class like this:

```
class Kayit_ol_acticvity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

In Java, if you don't specify the type of access on a class, it default to `package` which means it's only accessible to the other code in the same package. It needs to be `public` for Android classes to access it.

Change your code to this:

```
public class Kayit_ol_acticvity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Answer (score 0):

class `Kayit_ol_acticvity` should be `public`
Try this  :

```
public class Kayit_ol_acticvity extends AppCompatActivity {...
}
```

Documentation -[Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)  :

> A class may be declared with the modifier public, in which case that
> class is visible to all classes everywhere. If a class has no modifier
> (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only
> within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes)

P.S. It's good tone to use UpperCamelCase for naming classes and avoid _, so in yours  case it's `KayitOlActicvity`